# VS Code Python doesn't recognize match statement

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-3.10, vscode-python, python-jedi

When I use a match-case statement in Python in VS Code, it gives red squiggly lines and errors in the "problems" tab:

[image: Screenshot of VS Code as described above]

Comment: What version of Jedi are you using?

Comment: how do I check?

Comment: Idk, I just figure it's a version that doesn't yet recognize this syntax. From the answer, looks like support isn't implement yet

Comment: yeah, I switched to pylance and it works great

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I got a response from one of the vscode-python devs on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17745):

> Unfortunately Jedi (and it's underlying parser, parso) has not added support for the match statement yet. Please consider switching your language server to "Default"/"Pylance" as our Pylance language server already has support.

> As soon as Jedi makes a new release with match statement support we will take the update, but otherwise this is out of our hands. Since we have a language server that has support I'm a closing this issue.

Comment: Nowadays I use pylance, not jedi, but [it](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/1883) seems like Jedi still dosn't support `match`